# Customizable URL links based on a variable name

Tags: hyperlink, cgi

I have a url link that I generate from each run of a code. The url link is stored in a variable and it is then called by
a href.... (with the braces before)
I am  using cgi in python, if it helps
Each time I input a UniPROT ID, I generate a string based url

I want that url to be general each time I run. How do I do it?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDBNe.png) (Im unable to add image in the post, here the site is forcing me to use a url for this)

Each time I input a UniPROT ID, I generate a string based url

I want that url's hyperlink to be general each time I run. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The file name generate strategy should be changed to something related to image data.

Try using md5 of the image as the file name or some hash function.

Thus each time you get the same link no matter how many times you run the code.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear

The input is a string, not an image. The string gets converted on to a url id by adding input string with predefined string. 
for example: input= "U12343"
url _input= input + "https:/google"
Do you mean to say to use an md5 to convert the url_input id string to a hash value? function?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).